# Codeigniter form validation and pagination issue

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination

I am attempting my first codeigniter pagination program. I have a routine in the website that I am working on that let's you view records from a input value that is supplied through an input form. So in other words, I want to select all the records for someone that lives in New York, I then select New York from the drop-down list. From there, a controller function does the validation on the value and if it's good, you should see all the records from New York. However, I only see the first page of reords base on how records per page that I specified. When I try to go to the next page, it brings me back to the input form. Below is the code:

```
   public function view() {   
         $this->form_validation->set_rules('state', 'state', 'trim|required');

         if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
            $this->load->view('view');
         } else {
            $state = $this->input->post('state');

            // **** HERE IS WHERE THE PAGINATION ROUTINE STARTS ****

            // Setup the SELECT statement
            $qry = "SELECT city, state, person_name, person_gender, photo_url";
            $qry = $qry . " FROM membership m JOIN people p ON m.email_address = p.email_address";
            $qry = $qry . " WHERE state = '".$state."' ORDER BY state ASC, person_name ASC";

            // Set the limit and offset
            $limit = 2;
            $offset = ($this->uri->segment(3) != '' ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0);

            // Setup the $config variables for pagination
            $config['base_url'] = 'http://www.somewebsite.com/ci/index.php/cr/view';
            $config['total_rows'] = $this->db->query($qry)->num_rows();
            $config['uri_segment'] = 3;
            $config['per_page'] = $limit;
            $config['num_links'] = 10;
            $config['full_tag_open'] = '<div id="pagination">';
            $config['full_tag_close'] = '</div>';

            // Initialize the $config
            $this->pagination->initialize($config);

            // Limit and get the data
            $qry = $qry . " LIMIT {$limit} OFFSET {$offset}";
            $data['result_per_page'] = $this->db->query($qry)->result();

            // Now go and display the data
            $this->load->view('people', $data);

            // **** HERE IS WHERE THE PAGINATION ROUTINE STOPS ****

         }
   }
```

Now mind you, if I coded the pagination routine by itself, without the validation and hard coded the value 'NY' the pagination routine works perfect. However, as is, it keeps reloading the input form to select the state. I am relatively new to Codeigniter and PHP but is there a way to bypass the following code:

```
if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {
        $this->load->view('view');
     } else {
        $state = $this->input->post('state');
```

after the initial run through the function? I appreciate any help on this matter. Thank you.

Comment: Make sure you follow the documentation, you need to have a "page" segment in your base_url. Also, look at the links CI is generating for you, see if they have any errors or even make sense. http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/pagination.html

Comment: I'm a little confused about the page segment in the base_url. I thought that the uri_segment sets up the data where to begin displaying the data. Looked at that link you sent me and I am not really sure what I am looking for. The way I have my base_url setup is that cr is the controller and view is the function.

Comment: You should be using GET instead of POST for search.

Comment: @ahmad is right, this is where being able to see your actual html form would have been useful. Anyway, by using GET is how you then will be able to maintain a selected location within the dropdown list.